# join three tables in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, join

I ve thus far used join with two tables but now i want to join three tables which is shown in the below fig

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ms152507.75c9e4c3-260d-4b8d-8a27-b720d8f4470e%28en-US,SQL.90%29.gif))</sub>

I ve tried to join two tables,

```
SELECT O.OrderID,O.CustID,O.OrderTotal,C.Name from Orders
as O inner join Customers as C on O.CustID=C.CustID
```

how to join the third table with this.... Any suggestion...

Comment: What do you want to select from the tables?

Comment: @ individual customers order details

Comment: aah... you are beating database normalization to the ground :) (on  `OrderTotal` in `Orders`)

Comment: i cant get ur comment...

Comment: `[Orders].[OrderTotal]` is the sum of `[OrderItems].[OrderAmount]`. you will need an update for each new row in `[OrderItems]` to get the new sum ...

Comment: @dittodhole - of course on the flip-side, assuming optimising for read performance which typically occurs more, denormalising like this can be beneficial (saves accessing OrderItems table to sum up the total each time)

Comment: @AdaTheDev: i believe he is more doing joins like the asked one. assuming this: you already do a join, you can also do a `SUM()`

Comment: @dittodhole - yep sure. I was thinking about other common situations e.g. reporting on how total value of all orders by customer, where you're not interested in specifics of what was ordered.

Comment: @AdaTheDev: got the point ... :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do the same, with the third table:

```
SELECT O.OrderID,O.CustID,O.OrderTotal,C.Name, OC.OrderAmount
FROM Orders as O 
INNER JOIN Customers as C 
  ON O.CustID=C.CustID 
INNER JOIN OrderItems as OC
  ON O.OrderID=OC.OrderID
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just add another JOIN on to the end:

```
inner join OrderItems as OI ON O.OrderID= OI.OrderID
```

Note, that the top-level order info (order ID, customer ID, order total and customer name) will be returned for EACH order item within an order.
So depending on scenario, you may want to retrieve the top level data first, and then return all the order item detail separately to save returning lots of duplicate data. Depends on situation, but thought it worth a mention.

Answer (score 3):

```
    Select Customers.Name
    From OrderItems                            --      (Table 1)
    INNER JOIN Orders                          --      (Table 2)
    ON OrderItems.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
    INNER JOIN Customers                       --      (Table 3)
    ON Orders.CustID = Customers.CustID
    Where Customers.CustID = 2                 --      This will give you the name of the second customer in the third table using JOINS
```